# Haskell repeated use of fromIntegral when adding

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I have a number of `Word8` values that I am adding together. Because this could result in an overflow, the result needs to be a `Word16`.

Is there a better way to add all these values together than the following:

```
fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b + fromIntegral c + fromIntegral d + ...
```

which clutters the code without really adding any clarity?

Comment: `sum $ map fromIntegral [a, b, c, d, e, ...]`?

Comment: Yes, that works. But I'm afraid I may have to mix operators inbetween the numbers like + and -, so this might not work very well.

Comment: You could always bind new variable names to the widened values, and then use those in the actual calculation. But that's even _more_ typing, not less...

Comment: In that case maybe `fi = fromIntegral` might be best.

Comment: Well I think it could be less typing `(.-) x y = fromIntegral x - fromIntegral y ; ... ; val = a .+ b .- c .- d .+ e`.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to mix operations (as you suggest in your comments) you can use this trick to mass assign new variables

```
let [a', b', c', d'] = map fromIntegral [a, b, c, d]
in a' + b' - c' + d'
```

However, If you are to do that type of operations a lot, it's probably easier to define your own
"mixed" operators

```
let a !+ b = fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b
let a !- b = fromIntegral a - fromIntegral b

a !+ b !- c !+ d :: Word16
```